# UE4 can not compile c++ project with vs2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

So  when i start to create a c++ project under ue4.20.2 and vs2017,there is a error:

```
> ERROR: UnrealBuildTool Exception:
> Unable to find path to the Windows
> resource compiler under C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10 (version
> 10.0.16299.0)
```

And i find my vs2017 haven't the 10.0.16299.0 version sdk(I have 10.0.10240.0 and 10.0.17134.0).How can i do for this(how to specify the sdk version)?

Answer (score 0):

Unreal Engine 4 requires Windows Kits 8.1. You need to install it via Visual Studio Installer that come with Visual Studio 2017 in order to compile your code. And it looks like you are trying to use Windows SDK 10.